# call function inside of className react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I call the function for `getClass` for the `className` inside this example? The way I have it written out does not seem to call `getClass`.

```
var CreateList = React.createClass({
    getClass: function() {
        //some code to return className
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div className{this.getClass}>Example</div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Try changing `className{this.getClass}` to `className={'className' + this.getClass()}`.

Comment: Functions are called with `()`. If you don't call `this.getClass`, it won't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're referencing the instance of the `getClass()` function as opposed to calling the function. Try tweaking it like so:

```
render: function() {
    return(
        <div className={this.getClass()}>Example</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to send div element to getClass()  as parameter?

Comment: @AmirHosseinRezaei I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but you could in theory rewrite `getClass` to accept a node and work on it in `getClass`. You would have to first assign the div to a variable, update `getClass` to accept a param, and then call it.

I'm _really_ unsure about why you would do that to be honest. Why would you need the div to decide what class it should have?

Answer (score 2):

`className{this.getClass}` won't compile. Try this:

```
var CreateList = React.createClass({
    getClass: function() {
        //some code to return className
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div className={this.getClass()}>Example</div>
        );
    }
});
```

If you want the div to have a class name that starts with 'className', then prepend that string to the result of the call: `className={'className' + this.getClass()}`.

Answer (score 0):

functional component

```
const statusColor = () => {
    return 'red';
  };
```

```
<span className={statusColor()}>your text</span>
```