# React: can I set the className through a function call

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set the the className of a table row individually based on a value. Is there any way how i could do this when I want more than 2 different classNamese?

```html
 <tr className={() => {return this.getTableRowClassName(license.expiresAt)}} 
          key={license.id} >
```

Here is the function:

```js
    getTableRowClassName = function(date){
        if(((new Date(date) - Date.now()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) < 7) {
            return "table-danger";
        } else if(((new Date(date) - Date.now()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) < 14) {
            return "table-warning";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
´´´
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [call function inside of className react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011322/call-function-inside-of-classname-react-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

```
const value = this.getTableRowClassName(license.expiresAt);
...

<tr className={value}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes but you don't need to assign a .function to className you can directly call function

```
<tr className={this.getTableRowClassName(license.expiresAt)}>
```